# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar una iteración en una lista o en un dataframe?

Tags: array, r, bucles, dataframe

Quiero almacenar el resultado del "print" del siguiente código ya sea en un dataframe, o en una matriz o quizá incluso en una lista ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
> 
> for(i in 1:3) {
+     i = rep(sample(x = tabla$Valores, size = 5, replace = T))
+     print(i)}

[1] 2 7 8 3 5
[1] 7 8 4 1 7
[1] 2 4 3 3 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una lista, usando tu mismo `for`, simplemente creas el objeto fuera del ciclo y asignas cada elemento con cada interación:

```
lista <- list()
for(i in 1:3) {
  lista[[i]] <- rep(sample(x = tabla$Valores, size = 5, replace = T))
}
```

Como matriz, puedes hacer algo parecido, asignando cada fila:

```
matriz <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
for(i in 1:3) {
  matriz[i,] <- rep(sample(x = tabla$Valores, size = 5, replace = T))
}
```

Cuando se trata de un `data.frame`, la forma más cómoda podría ser usar `rbind()` para ir adicionando fila a fila, pero esto tiene un grave problema de performance, por lo que es buena práctica no emplear este método. Lo que se suele hacer es convertir directamente la matriz en un `data.frame`:

```
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(matriz)
```